# How to get token from sub rule context ANTLR 4?

Tags: antlr4

This is my image structure ANTLR 4 parsing tree gui:

[image]

This my listener rule enterDeclaration :

```
   public void enterDeclaration(ADTCParser.DeclarationContext ctx) { 

    TokenStream tokens = parser.getTokenStream();
    String initDeclarationList = tokens.getText(ctx.initDeclarationList());
   }
```

to get tokens from initDeclarationList such as :

```
String initDeclarationList = tokens.getText(ctx.initDeclarationList());
String parameterDeclaration = ???
```

And my questions is "How to get tokens from sub-rule "parameterDeclaration" from " structure based on the image above ?

BTW, im using grammar C in ANTLR 4
this is link for grammar : https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4

Comment: Need to show the relevant parser rules.

Comment: im using grammar C EBNF in ANTLR 4

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
ADTCParser.ParameterDeclarationContext context = parser.declaration()
        .initDeclaratorList()
        .initDeclarator()
        .declarator()
        .directDeclarator()
        .parameterTypeList()
        .parameterList()
        .parameterDeclaration();
```

where `parser.declaration()` is your `ADTCParser.DeclarationContext ctx` parameter.

Comment: Thanks alot Mister Bart Kiers, it works in my project